# I would like to use numbers 0-9 for mysql table names. How should I write sql queries using `` backticks to protect against sql query errors?

Tags: php, mysql

A user can post any topic title on my website, including pure numbers (eg. 12345). The topic title becomes the name of the table in mysql. I've encountered MYSQL errors in various places when testing out a number as a topic title, and have determined the problem is that I didn't use backtick marks to make sql queries.

How should I properly write all my queries to keep any possible title (table) from returning a mysql error? Code example below. What other potential table titles could cause problems?

```
<?php
for ($i=0; $i<4; $i++) {
// select by rand
$offset_result = mysql_query( " SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(*)) AS `offset` FROM `$random_slash[$i]` ");
$offset_row = mysql_fetch_object( $offset_result ); 
$offset = $offset_row->offset;
$result = mysql_query( " SELECT * FROM `$random_slash[$i]` LIMIT $offset, 1 " );

//$rs = @mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {?>
        <div class="quadrant">
            <h2 class="alignleft"><a href="/<?php echo $random_slash[$i]; ?>">
```

As a note - the tick marks seem to denote code

Comment: Could you post your database structure? You really shouldn't be using a separate table for every topic.

Comment: I think you need to rethink your database scheme, topics becoming tables sounds unnecessary and a bad idea in general.

Answer (score 5):

> A user can post any topic title on my website, including pure numbers (eg. 12345). The topic title becomes the name of the table in mysql.

Noooooo! Don't do this.

The topic title should become a value, not the name of a table.

Use one table to store the topics, one row per topic. Use a second table to store the children of that topic. Use a foreign key to link the child to the parent topic.

Answer (score 0):

Mark's answer already shows what the real issue is, and how to solve it. But since you stated your question as being about backticks, here is some information about them:

- They should be used to escape table and column names
- They are not required if your table and column names contain only `[a-zA-Z_]` (except for names that are already reserved words)
- They allow you to name tables and columns with arbitrary strings, containing spaces and many special characters (not *any*), as you wanted to do, but this is **not recommended** (mainly for compatibility).